# Generic "a man" versus plural "men" in English

Tags: determiners, grammatical-number

In English, is there any difference between the following two?

- A man never enjoys his authority being questioned.
- Men never enjoy their authority being questioned.

Comment: **A** man = an/one example of a man; any random male individual. Usually used in reference to a particular case. -- There is no relevant context but "a man", with "man" emphasised, could mean "a stereotypical / archetypal male" as opposed to a coward, an effeminate man, a lesser male, etc. -- **Men** = all men. This is clearly a generalisation.

Comment: Do you intend to distinguish between men and women?

Comment: 'The following two' is misleading. Adding different emphases (here masked) gives different readings, as Greybeard points out. In general, I'd agree that the choice of the indefinite generic particularises more; it's also more formal. Taken together, this makes the statement more forceful, less easy to dismiss with casual assent. Also, there's more of a pull towards the gender categorisation.

Comment: There's a rhetorical difference in that "men" probably sounds more forceful than "a man", but questions about rhetoric are generally off-topic and belong in writing SE or literature SE. Do you mean to ask if there is a difference in meaning, which is how everyone seems to be trying to answer it?

Comment: @Stuart removed the word rhetorical.

Answer (score 1):

```
A man never enjoys his authority being questioned.
Men never enjoy their authority being questioned.
```

The usage of "A man" is meant to convey that "One never enjoys..."
Whereas the use of "Men never enjoy" is a generalization as Greybeard correctly points out. There is a layer greater than a generalization of *men*, one of these guys, that *A man* points to. It brings the point being made, or claimed, to philosophical or mythical proportions.

It is not dissimilar to a favorite distinction I enjoy. When describing Xandu, the Hearst mansion, it was said it was how God would live if He had money. Those that are said to Have *the* money, might afford the mansion, a particular thing. Those that had *money* could afford it and anything else. It is a categorical distinction.